# Upgrade to Kernel 6.2 broke bluetooth headset microphone

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, headset

Since my Ubuntu (22.04) was upgraded to Kernel 6.2.0-26 , my headphones (Sony WH-1000XM5) can no longer connect with the headset (handsfree_head_unit) profile (a2dp_sink, i.e. audio only, works fine). Booting back into kernel 5 (5.19.0-50-generic) "fixes" the issue.

Trying to change profile:

```
➜  ~ pacmd set-card-profile bluez_card.AC_80_0A_1A_D6_56 off                
➜  ~ pacmd set-card-profile bluez_card.AC_80_0A_1A_D6_56 handsfree_head_unit
Failed to set card profile to 'handsfree_head_unit'.
```

sysctl logs (not very helpful):

```
Aug 15 17:33:40 pulseaudio[4088]: Refused to switch profile to handsfree_head_unit: Not connected
```

Anyone has a similar issue when upgrading to Kernel 6, or any tips on what might be going wrong?

Comment: Haven't tested with other kernels, but I have Ubuntu 22.04, Sony WH-1000XM5, kernel 6.2.0-26-generic and when I try to change Bluetooth device to audio profile Handsfree Head Unit (HFP) I get "Failed to change profile to handsfree_head_unit"

Comment: Well, I installed latest updates, and initially thought that fixed this issue. Changing audio profile from Bluetooth Devices worked a few times. Then had one handsfree_head_unit failure again, so the problem seems to still exist. What seemed to work was (using Bluetooth devices): disconnect headset, connect again, after a few seconds switch profile to HFP. Will have to see if that works reliably or not.

Comment: Indeed unpairing then pairing again works some percentage of the time, but then when turning the headset off and back on again it no longer works. "Glad" to know I'm not the only one though

Comment: I also have this problem, with the same headset model. I would be happy to help looking for a solution, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: I have this issue too - Sony WH-1000XM4 and Lenovo P1 Gen 5, Ubuntu 22.04, kernel 6.2.0-26-generic. I tried the latest mainline kernel (v6.4.11-060411) and the problem persists.

Comment: I have "Connect to 2 devices simultaneously" enabled on my Sony headphones. Device 1 is my Android phone (typically pairs first) and device 2 is the Ubuntu laptop. If I disable Bluetooth on Android to allow the laptop to be the only connected device, it sometimes allows me to successfully switch to HFP.

When connected to two devices, the Sony Headphones Android app shows an icon beside the device currently 'playing music'. If I have music playing on Android and select HFP on Ubuntu, the phone stops playing music and the headset switches to HFP successfully. Still intermittent though.

Comment: Created bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-6.2/+bug/2032761

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same Sony bluetooth headset and experienced the same as yours. The best solution is that we just have to wait for the latest update from kernel 6.2. Like kernel 6.2.1 or kernel 6.3 or something.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see anything that matches on [Ubuntu Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu?field.searchtext=bluetooth%20kernel%206.2&search=Search&field.status%3Alist=NEW&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITH_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITHOUT_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=CONFIRMED&field.status%3Alist=TRIAGED&field.status%3Alist=INPROGRESS&field.status%3Alist=FIXCOMMITTED&field.assignee=&field.bug_reporter=&field.omit_dupes=on&field.has_patch=&field.has_no_package=) searching for 'bluetooth kernel 6.2', so someone on this thread that owns the hardware may want to file a bug with some specifics to get the issue on the radar (and receive updates on the fix).

Another place to look / file a bug would be [Kernel Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/)

Comment: Yes good call-out, I ended up not having a lot of time to go through it - since I've never reported a bug on launchpad before - but went through the trouble of doing it now: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-6.2/+bug/2032761

Answer (score 0):

(Have to do as an answer as I don’t have the 50 Reputations yet to comment.)

Not sure how helpful this is but tangential problem(s).  My USB headset (with mic) caused Firefox to stop working (!).  Thunderbird worked fine.  Saw problem reported in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1951491 suggested unplugging the USB headset.    (Mumbling to self: what’s Firefox got to do with a headset?)

Day or so later ran sudo firefox  and received some quirky errors:
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
[GFX1-]: vaapitest: ERROR
[GFX1-]: vaapitest: VA-API test failed: failed to initialise VAAPI connection.
Also saw some pulse errors which seemed to refer to pulseaudio.
Also had noted some references to directories which don’t exist here: /run/user/0 (subdir ‘0’ not exist) and  /usr/run/1000/bus (subdir ‘bus’ not exist at the time of testing).

Noted later nothing was listed in Settings > Sound.  I do not know when I lost audio output from the computer as I am using a Raspberry Pi for streaming music in to an amp and speakers.

I did have to reboot with the USB headset unplugged  to get things to finally work.  At first Firefox would only work via Terminal (better than nothing!) and a try or two later it worked via Favourites.

The USB Headset still is not detected: MPOW PA071A.

uname -r:   6.2.0-26-generic
cat /etc/os-release:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
lsusb:      ...Well guess that would do it: I don’t see being detected!

LIS, tangential information, hopefully somewhat helpful in tracking the error.